# How to use VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN client

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, visualsvn-server

I will soon start working on a project and the source code is on a remote location. However, I have got the source code on my C drive in a folder. I have VisualSVN server and TortoiseSVN client on my machine. I will be controlling the project work with two other people working on the same project. How do I create a repository on Visual SVN from the local folder?

Comment: See the [VisualSVN Server Getting Started guide](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/getting-started/).

Answer (score 8):

I have **Visual SVN** setup on a Virtual Machine so I'll try and help as best as I can. I used subversion for a bunch of university projects so I have a pretty good idea of how Visual SVN works. You don't create a repository from a local folder. It's all done through Visual SVN.

**Here is what you will have to do:**

1. On **Visual SVN**, right-click on **Repositories** and choose the **Create New Repository** option.
2. Choose a suitable name (e.g. "MyRepository") for the repository, remembering to not include any spaces.
3. Once that is done, create a folder anywhere on your computer. If you have Tortoise SVN installed correctly, your context menu should have a bunch of new options. The one you need is titled **SVN Checkout**.
4. Right-click on the newly created folder and select **SVN Checkout**. A Dialog should appear prompting you to enter the details required to connect to a repository.
5. To connect to your repository **(Step 2)** you'll need to use **HTTPS**, followed by the local IP address of the computer (your computer in this case) Visual SVN is hosted on, followed by `/svn/NameOfYourRepository`.
6. For example: If the local IP address of your computer is `192.168.0.something` and the name of your repository is `MyRepository`, to connect to that repository you'll have to type: `https://192.168.0.something/svn/MyRepository` in the **URL of repository** field. You shouldn't have to change anything else on the Dialog that appears after following **Step 4**.
7. If you have entered the correct details, an "Authentication" dialog should appear prompting you to enter a **Username** and **Password** combination. Enter your local username and password, which should successfully connect you to your repository. If you're using an **Administrator** account you shouldn't have any issues connecting.
8. If you're successful, the **Checked Out** folder will appear with a Green Tick indicating that it is under version control. Any files/folders you place within there will be put under version control, but not by default.
9. To place them under version control, you'll have to Right-click on the files/folders and select **Tortoise SVN** - **Add** - and then on the Root folder you'll have to select **SVN Commit**.

**Additional Notes:** When working on the files, it would be a good idea to use the **Get Lock** and **Release Lock** options. However, it would be even better if you set specific working times for each user as someone may forget to release the files.

This is by no means a comprehensive guide. If you have any questions, I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Excellent. It solved my Problem. Thanks a lot :)